# All sites except Meta.SE have wrong icons in inbox, achievements, and site switcher

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

This happened within the last hour or so on Mi Yodeya:

[image: SO icon for SE chat rooms]

[image: wrong/missing icons in site switcher]

The achievements drop-down is similarly affected.

This happens on every site I've tried (responsive or old design, with or without an account) *except* for Meta.SE, which has the correct icons.

I see that *some* (but not all) HNQ icons in the right column are also affected, but haven't looked for a pattern there.

I know that "meta is different", but this isn't the kind of "different" we usually see.

Comment: also a related report on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374126/hot-network-questions-have-broken-icons